# Grabbing multiple rows from sudzc

Tags: ios5, sudzc

I'm trying to return multiple rows from a sudzc wsdl.  I have loaded the result into a dictionary.  The code below gives me the first result.  How do I retrieve all of the results instead of just the first one?    I'm looking for CSHR_POS_NAME where [ID.text intValue] == CSHR_NUM.

```
dict = [resp objectForKey:@"TC"];
if( ( dict == nil ) || ![dict isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] ) {
    NSLog( @"WARNING: %@", [dict description]);
    return;
}
    desc = [[dict objectForKey:@"CSHR_POS_NAME"]copy];
    CashierNum = [[dict objectForKey:@"CSHR_NUM"]copy];

    NSLog(@"Name: %@ and Cashier Number: %@",desc, CashierNum);
```

I was able to accomplish in vb:

```
If dsCashiers.Table("TC").Rows.Count > 0 Then
...
```

Comment: It's a sudzc problem.  It loops through the deserialize overwriting the previous node.

Comment: see solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235496/sudzc-deserializeasdictionary-over-written-dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[d setObject:v forKey:[child name]]; 
NSString* key = [child name]; 
id check = [d objectForKey:key]; 
if( check != nil ) { 

NSInteger next = 1; 
key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d", [child name], next]; 
check = [d objectForKey:key]; 
while( check != nil ) { 

    next++; 
    key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d", [child name], next]; 
    check = [d objectForKey:key]; 
} 
[d setObject:v forKey:key]; 
} 
[d setObject:v forKey:[child name]];
```