# Sudzc deserializeAsDictionary: over written dictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, sudzc

The Sudzc generated code is over writing a dictionary for deserialized nodes.  If I use the NSLog(@"The Child Node: %@", [[[element children] objectAtIndex:0] stringValue]); it will write the correct items out each time it passed through.  When I try to retrieve the results in code only the last one is available (Jackson 3).  What am I doing wrong?

```
// Deserializes the element in a dictionary.
+(id)deserializeAsDictionary:(CXMLNode*)element {

if([element childCount] == 1) {
    CXMLNode* child = [[element children] objectAtIndex:0];
    if([child kind] == CXMLTextKind) 
    {
         NSLog(@"The Child Node: %@", [[[element children] objectAtIndex:0] stringValue]);
        return [[[element children] objectAtIndex:0] stringValue];

    }
}

NSMutableDictionary* d = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for(CXMLNode* child in [element children]) {
    id v = [Soap deserialize:child];
    if(v == nil) { v = [NSNull null]; }
    [d setObject:v forKey:[child name]];
}
return d;
}
```

NSLog:

```
2012-04-19 14:13:07.802 Management[3043:10703] Hopefully Child: Allen
2012-04-19 14:13:07.803 Management[3043:10703] Hopefully Child: 1
2012-04-19 14:13:07.804 Management[3043:10703] Hopefully Child: John
2012-04-19 14:13:07.804 Management[3043:10703] Hopefully Child: 2
2012-04-19 14:13:07.805 Management[3043:10703] Hopefully Child: Jackson
2012-04-19 14:13:07.805 Management[3043:10703] Hopefully Child: 3
```

XML:

```
<TC diffgr:id="TC1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
 <CSHR_POS_NAME>Allen</CSHR_POS_NAME>                            
    <CSHR_NUM>66</CSHR_NUM>
</TC>

<TC diffgr:id="TC2" msdata:rowOrder="1">                                    
  <CSHR_POS_NAME>John</CSHR_POS_NAME>
    <CSHR_NUM>2</CSHR_NUM>
    </TC>

<TC diffgr:id="TC3" msdata:rowOrder="2">
<CSHR_POS_NAME>Jackson</CSHR_POS_NAME>
<CSHR_NUM>3</CSHR_NUM>
</TC>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved (changed the soap.m):

```
[d setObject:v forKey:[child name]]; 
NSString* key = [child name]; 
id check = [d objectForKey:key]; 
if( check != nil ) { 

    NSInteger next = 1; 
    key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d", [child name], next]; 
    check = [d objectForKey:key]; 
    while( check != nil ) { 

        next++; 
        key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d", [child name], next]; 
        check = [d objectForKey:key]; 
    } 
    [d setObject:v forKey:key]; 
} 
[d setObject:v forKey:[child name]];
```

Answer (score 1):

as soon as I get enough rep points I will, but I did notice that the code begins and ends with

```
  [d setObject:v forKey:[child name]];
```

and for me I had to remove the initial  line, and that fixed it for me, so the code looks like this:

```
// Deserializes the element in a dictionary.
 +(id)deserializeAsDictionary:(CXMLNode*)element {

if([element childCount] == 1) {
    CXMLNode* child = [[element children] objectAtIndex:0];
    if([child kind] == CXMLTextKind) {            
    return [[[element children] objectAtIndex:0] stringValue];
    }
}   
NSMutableDictionary* d = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for(CXMLNode* child in [element children]) {

id v = [Soap deserialize:child];
if(v == nil) { v = [NSNull null]; }

//[d setObject:v forKey:[child name]]; //seems to be duped (maybe my bad)
    //Extended by iDev on StackOverflow
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235496/sudzc-deserializeasdictionary-over-written-dictionary/10358458#10358458
    NSString* key = [child name]; 
    id check = [d objectForKey:key]; 
    if( check != nil ) {             
        NSInteger next = 1;             
        key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%04d", [child name], next];
        check = [d objectForKey:key]; 
        while( check != nil ) {                 
            next++; 
            key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%04d", [child name], next]; 
            check = [d objectForKey:key]; 
        } 
        [d setObject:v forKey:key]; 
    } 
    [d setObject:v forKey:[child name]]; 
    //End Extension
}
return d;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I found that you have to put an else block in as well:

```
if( check != nil ) {             
    NSInteger next = 1;             
    key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%04d", [child name], next];
    check = [d objectForKey:key]; 
    while( check != nil ) {                 
        next++; 
        key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%04d", [child name], next]; 
        check = [d objectForKey:key]; 
    } 
    [d setObject:v forKey:key]; 
} else {
    [d setObject:v forKey:[child name]];
}
//End Extension
```

Otherwise elements in 'd' will be overwritten because setObject is called twice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm uncertain on how you applied your fix, are you replacing the entire code in *deserializeAsDictionary* or are you appending to the end of the code?

see there's a for loop where the code line

```
  [d setObject:v forKey:[child name]];
```

is found, so I'm guessing you simply extended that so that instead of closing the for loop you simply extend it here, is this right?

Answer (score 0):

I was having issues with the above code - it was overwriting the first entry each time - ie I would get a list of 4 items and the first and fourth would be duplicated.

After a lot of exhausting stepping thru code (love recursive code NOT), I found what I believe was the issue;

My code is as follows:

```
    if( check != nil ) {
        NSInteger next = 1;
        key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%04d", [child name], next];
        check = [d objectForKey:key];
        while( check != nil ) {
            next++;
            key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%04d", [child name], next];
            check = [d objectForKey:key];
        }
        [d setObject:v forKey:key];  
    }
    else
    {
          [d setObject:v forKey:[child name]];
    }
```